# Vacuum Contactor Wiring Diagrams

Tags: high-voltage, contactor

In reviewing the following wiring schematics for a vacuum contactor, I can't wrap my head around why things are the way they are.

[image: Vacuum Contactor Wiring Diagrams]
[Source > Downloads > Catalogues](http://www.eatoncanada.ca/EatonCA/ProductsSolutions/Electrical/ProductsandServices/AutomationandControl/ContactorsStartersandProtectiveRelays/ElectromechanicalContactorsandStarters/VacuumContactorsandStarters/index.htm#tabs-2)

---

**Wiring Diagram #1, Size 4 Contactor**

My thought-train for the circuit is:

1. START is pressed, powers the circuit.
2. AUX is not powered so it shorts the resistor/capacitor
3. Coil M receives the fully rectified line voltage.
4. Sometime later, AUX closes and the resistor/capacitor are in series with the rectifier.

What is the purpose of this resistor and capacitor? Is this just to reduce the voltage on coil M? M would require a specific VA to keep it energized, so wouldn't dropping the voltage simply increase the current required?

Bonus: What would be the purpose of substituting the resistor/capacitor for a resistor and potentiometer in series? Tune the voltage at the rectifier?

---

**Wiring Diagram #2, Size 5 and 6 Starter**

This circuit doesn't include the resistor/capacitor pair, but it has two coils in series. This didn't make sense to me so I researched some and found [this](http://www.eaton.mx/EN/ecm/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&allowInterrupt=1&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&noSaveAs=0&Rendition=Primary&dDocName=IL17089) excerpt:

> The operating coil has a "figure-eight" shape and is really two coils in series, with a connection to their common point. [...] When adjusted correctly, this contact allows a relatively high current through the pickup winding, and as the controller closes, the contact inserts the holding winding, which reduces the coil current to a low value [...]

That makes general sense. One coil for high current draw, one coil for holding current draw. What doesn't quite make sense is, again, how putting them in series *reduces* the total draw. Don't they each need their required VA? Or, does the holding winding essentially knock-out the pickup winding? I think I might be overthinking it as I rarely see coils in series, always paralleled.

---

Lastly, with both of these coils being fed off full-bridge rectifiers with no smoothing capacitors, do they ever risk opening as the DC voltage bounces to 0 V?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola, no. Work assignment. The circuit these questions came from is confidential but it's a hybrid of the two above. I need to make some changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this resistor and capacitor

After full activation, C raises impedance with low loss, R lowers Q to avoid LC  resonance.

> potentiometer in series?

- too lossy (hot) for holding current.

> Don't they each need their required VA?

- No.   S is rated for  Start, R when added to S reduces to holding power for Run operation. They dont’ have to be identical coil impedance.

> do they ever risk opening as the DC voltage bounces to 0 V

- No. these would shading pole type relays like those that are AC/DC

Comment: I’m from the Peg too.

Comment: In each of the scenarios, the impedance is just being increased after pickup, right? And the purpose of this increase is to reduce power draw?

Comment: Yes 2pi f L + 1/2pifC + R = Z (f). It assumes Aux contact occurs at same time or after shortly.

Comment: OK, making more sense. My initial assumption was that the power requirement of the coil would change dynamically but I guess that's not the case. Some work is done to move between the inrush and holding specifications.

Side note: very cool that you're from around here. What a small world the internet makes.

Comment: Back EMF rises with velocity then stops so the Run/Start Current Ratios depending on these impedance ratio.  Yes small world.   and my "son-in-law"  is an EE Prof at U of T and his Dad taught me some courses at U of M in early '70's